Notation Dilemma in Formulas
Considering:
1.
$$ w^{(k+1)} = w^{(k)} - \eta g_{w^{(k)}}$$
Given this, do I need to define $g_{w^{(k)}}$ with the index?:
2.
$$
g_{w^{(k)}} = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \nabla_{w^{(k)}} L(h(x_i, w^{(k)}), y_{i})
$$
Or can I use the simplified notation $g$ right away, expressed as:
3.
$$
g = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \nabla_{w} L(h(x_i, w), y_{i})
$$
If I only use (3), does the reader know, or is it then clear, that when I write $g_{w^{(k)}}$, I also mean to insert $w^{(k)}$ into the equation instead of just $w$?
Or is this not correct and I need to use a functional notation like $g(w^{(k)})$ and then define g as a function like this:
4.
$$
g(w) = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \nabla_{w} L(h(x_i, w), y_{i})
$$
Or is everything incorrect/correct? I am a little bit confused and also sorry, if this is a really dumb question.

You can use any notation you like, as long as it's not ambiguous. Since it depends on $w^{(k)}$, I would avoid writing $g$ with no qualification because that would imply that it takes the same value regardless of $k$ - and you definitely can't just use $w$ in a formula if you haven't defined what that means.
Is there any reason you can't use $g_k$ or $g^{(k)}$? Either would indicate that it's indexed in the same way as $w^{(k)}$. To me, $g_{w^{(k)}}$ implies that there's a table of $g_j$ values and you have to look up what value of $j$ corresponds to $w^{(k)}$.

Thanks for your answer! Yes, you are absolutely right, I could've used also only $g_k$ or just $g^{(k)}$, my fault. Thanks for the suggestion!
Is there any difference between using 2. and 4.?

Not hugely, and they're both valid. 4 has some uses if it matters that $g$ is a function of $w$, e.g. if you want to look at its derivative.

If you introduce some notion in 1) I'd go with 2, because then there is no ambiguity. You can use 3 or 4 and hope for the best but there will always be someone that will get confused. I personally hate it when authors deviate from their previously introduced notation but that is probably subjective.
If you want to use a simplified version, it's best to leave a comment about it akin to "For convenience, we will now drop the subscript and simply write $g$"

Thanks for your answer!
